# How to load a .hdf5 model in S3 to EC2 directly?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hdf5

I used keras created a .hdf5 model and stored it in S3. Now I want to load this model from S3 to EC2 directly? I wonder what is the best practice to do this? I mean I can `aws s3 cp` to move the model down from s3 to ec2 but I feel like there should be better way to do it.

I know I can use load_model (from keras.model) but the file have to be on EC2.

Also, how do I directly write thing from ec2 to s3 instead of copying them to s3?

Thank you!

Comment: are you using python in EC2?